# how to get connection's ip in NGROK

Tags: python-2.7, ngrok

Can I determine IP address of user accessing a Python(2.7.9) server behind ngrok?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Could you try clarifying?

Comment: Are you trying to get a clients IP address when they visit your site that's being served through ngrok?

Comment: yes, im trying to get the ip of the client that have connect to my site that's being served through ngrok.

Comment: well, i read it and the only thing with ip is IP Whitelist Tunnel Access, that i dont need because i want everyone to connect to my server. i found nothing else so maybe someone here knows what to do